# String data, right truncation error is being thrown during select

Tags: java, sql, exception, hsqldb

I get *"String data, right truncation"* exception when I try to execute this statement on data stored in HSQLDB.

```
select case 
          when InquiryDate = '' then '' 
          WHEN InquiryDate like '%NOTDATE%' then 'UNKNOWN' 
          else  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(InquiryDate,'MMDDYY'), 'YYYYMMDD') 
       end as "InquiryDate" 
from T_INQUIRY
```

Any idea why? InquiryDate field is defined as VARCHAR(1000)

Comment: Try executing `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'T_INQUIRY'` and reconfirm the size of VARCHAR type columns.

Comment: I confirmed that it does have varchar(1000) using the above query <COLUMN_NAME>INQUIRYDATE</COLUMN_NAME>
<DATA_TYPE>CHARACTER VARYING</DATA_TYPE>
 <CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH>1000</CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH>

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **exact** error message you got and the Java code that triggers the error. [edit] your question do to add code or additional information in comments

Answer (score 0):

The query works fine in the latest HSQLDB (2.35 / 2.40).

To get it to work in the version you are using, cast one of the string literals to VARCHAR. For example:

```
select case 
      when InquiryDate = '' then CAST('' AS VARCHAR(8))
      WHEN InquiryDate like '%NOTDATE%' then 'UNKNOWN' 
      else  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(InquiryDate,'MMDDYY'), 'YYYYMMDD') 
   end as "InquiryDate" 
from T_INQUIRY
```

Note `InquiryDate` is not used as a return value directly. Your version uses the type of the empty string and 'UNKNOWN', which is CHAR, not VARCHAR.

It should also work if you use the column value directly:

```
select case 
      when InquiryDate = '' then InquiryDate
      WHEN InquiryDate like '%NOTDATE%' then 'UNKNOWN' 
      else  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(InquiryDate,'MMDDYY'), 'YYYYMMDD') 
   end as "InquiryDate" 
from T_INQUIRY
```

Comment: Thank you! I just used a more recent HSQL - 2.4 and it seemed to do the trick for me.